# One-point subset of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Proposition:
>
> Let X be a non-empty set and let $\mathbf{B}$ be the collection of all one-point subsets $\left \{ x \right \}$ of X. Then $\mathbf{B}$ is a basis for the discrete topology on X.

My question is embarrassingly trivial but what is a *one-point subset* of a non-empty set X?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means let $\mathbf{B} = \{\{x\}| x \in X\}$. Note that $x \in X$ but $\{x\} \subset X$, because the latter is a set.

Comment: It's perhaps confusing because $\mathbf{B}$ is isomorphic to $X$, so it may seem a bit pointless to construct it. But, if you permit the pun, [that's kind of the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology): open sets are always useful to consider in topology, but single points usually aren't (_except_ in the discrete case, and arguably this is because the isomorphism to single-point sets is continuous here).

Comment: One-member subsets of a set are sometimes called singletons, for brevity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subset which contains exactly one element. Also known as a "singleton". For example, $\{\pi\}$ and $\{-5\}$ are one-point subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

(The word "point" is often used for "element" in topological and geometric contexts.)

Comment: On a tangent to my main question: am I correct to say that the cardinality of $\mathbf{B}$ is the cardinality of the non-empty set X?

Comment: @Mathematicing: Yes, that's exactly right. You can make a bijection $f:X\to\mathbf{B}$ by defining $f(x)=\{x\}$, therefore they have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

One point set is set consisting of only one element of $X$.

on $\mathbb{Z}$ one point sets are $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}...$.

Theorem you give means $B=\{ \{x \} : x\in X \}$ is basis for discrete Topology on $X$.